# How to add multiple URL types to `background-image` CSS property?

Tags: html, css, image

I currently have the following HTML code:

```html
<header style="background-image:url(/images/header.webp)">
```

However, on some browsers (mainly older versions of Safari), [webp is not supported](https://caniuse.com/webp). So I'd like to specify a fallback png image URL.

Using a `picture` tag I can do something like:

```html
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="/images/header.webp">
    <source type="image/png" srcset="/images/header.png">
</picture>
```

How can I do the same thing using the `background-image` CSS property?

Note, I can **NOT** use a CSS stylesheet for this, I must use the HTML `style` attribute. This is due to how I'm dynamically generating the HTML content.

Comment: Try this


`<header style="background-image:url(/images/header.webp), url(/images/header-2.webp)">`

Comment: @Ashish I don't have 2 webp images. I have 1 png and 1 webp. Based on https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_backgrounds.asp, that code looks like it is for multiple backgrounds. Which is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for webp background image, with a fallback to png if the browser doesn't support webp.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/#using-webp-images-in-css) recommends using a feature detection library like Modernizr to add a class to the HTML root (like `html.webp`) in supporting browsers, so you can write CSS that swaps a JPG or PNG image for a WEBP image:

```
.elementWithBackgroundImage {
  background-image: url("image.png");
}

.webp .elementWithBackgroundImage {
  background-image: url("image.webp");
}
```

Comment: That is helpful. But I'm not sure it'll work since I can't use a CSS stylesheet and have to use the `style` attribute (due to how I'm dynamically generating the HTML content).

Comment: @CharlieFish How are you dynamically generating the HTML? If you're doing it in-browser using JS, you could use feature detection to include the proper image format inline. If you're generating the DOM server-side, you could output a `<style>` attribute to the DOM with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can call multiple backgrounds. The second URL will act as a fallback if the browser can't find the first one.

```
<header style="background-image:url('/images/header.webp'), url('/images/header.png')">
```

Note: I am unsure whether the browser will opt to try and use the .webp even if it's unsupported. You should test this out to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple backgrounds including `<div>` inside another `<div>`.
Using  `url(...)left no-repeat;`  and `url(...)right no-repeat;`  those backgrounds will be visible, and by setting the width you can even intersect those urls, see the example below.

```
.backup1
{
    height: 15px;
    width: 26px;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='svgXML' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='15px' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='15px' fill='%237e32d3'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M19 9h-4V3H9v6H5l7 7 7-7zM5 18v2h14v-2H5z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") left no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right:2px;
}

.backup2
{
    height: 15px;
    width: 26px;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg class='svgXML' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='15px' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='15px' fill='%23009900'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M9 16h6v-6h4l-7-7-7 7h4zm-4 2h14v2H5z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") right no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
}

.btn
{
   opacity: 0.75;
}

.btn:hover
{
    opacity:1;
}
```

View the result: https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/rbju7sxq/4/